# Conversão de string em datetime com formato especifico

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão

Tenho uma `string` no seguinte formato: **16Mar2009(mon)**, mas não estou conseguindo converter em `datetime`.

```
 string format = "dMMMyyyy(dd)";
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("16Mar2009(mon)", format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinha um erro básico no formato, falta uma letra `d` no dia e dia da semana. O certo é assim:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("16Mar2009(mon)", "ddMMMyyyy(ddd)", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uY9BNv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3KCCzv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseExact.cs).

Referência: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)