# Converter string para DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Como pegar de uma `string` algo como "30/01/2015", por exemplo, e convertê-lo para `datetime` e mantendo esse mesmo formato de data? Podendo validar a data.

Comment: Relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68247/10315

Comment: Vi esse pergunta mas achei que a resposta pudesse ser outra.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: tranquilo @Ayo  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode manter formato de data quando converte para `DateTime`. Este tipo guarda uma data. Ponto. Pra ser mais preciso uma informação de um ponto no tempo. Tem a data e o horário.

Se quer ela em um formato específico para apresentá-la em algum lugar qualquer, você converterá ela para *string*, até porque muitos formatos só podem ser obtidos com textos, e *string* é o tipo para texto. Na prática mesmo em formatos simples (algo como "30012015"), também será uma *string*. Não importa onde vai usar esta informação.

Você pode usar o [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) para converter. Mas eu prefiro quase sempre o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Ele não gera exceção se o dado é inválido.

```
var dataFormatada = "";
if (DateTime.TryParse("30/01/2015", out var data)) dataFormatada = data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Parse.cs).

Relacionadas:

- [Conversão de string de data para datetime C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68247/101) (by Wellington Avelino)
- [Conversão de string em datetime com formato especifico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47673/101)