# Como fazer o Visual Studio interpretar um horario que seja maior que 23hrs e menor que 6hrs ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, if, time

Tenho um função que é chamada e deve entrar na condição onde a hora agora seja maior que 23 horas e menor que 6 horas ao mesmo tempo, no entanto o código entra em conflito com essa condição e por isso nunca entra na condição.

Segue meu código:

```
  string valor_horaC1 = horarioC1Label1.Text;//o valor na label é 23:00
   string valor_horaC2 = horarioC2Label1.Text;//o valor na label é 06:00
   var var_horaC1_2 = TimeSpan.Parse(valor_horaC1);
  var var_horaA2 = TimeSpan.Parse(valor_horaA2);



    if ((hora_now >= var_horaC1) && (hora_now <= var_horaC2)) //Condição para o Turno C
            {
                if (horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")
                {
                    label8.Text = "Turno 3";

                }

            }
```

Comment: sim eu sei que tenho que utilizar as data juntos mas acontece que as datas mudam conforme passam as horas

Comment: O confilto não está na condição e sim nos Tipos que você está utilizando... O que é `hora_now`??? se você deixar as suas variáveis com um nome mais descritivo ou explicar melhor a sua lógica e o que está tentando fazer a gente consegue ajudar mais

Comment: @568lu Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Em primeiro lugar [não é possível o Visual Studio fazer algo assim porque ele é um IDE, é uma ferramenta para escrever códigos e não é função dele calcular datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Mas se quer saber como programar em C# para fazer isto, dá para responder.

Vou ignorar os erros que daria outros tipos de problema e nem compilaria.

Já um erro neste código porque nada garante que o dado escrito no campo de texto estará no formato correto, se não estiver seu código quebrará. Isto pode ser visto em algumas perguntas como essa: [Converter string para DateTime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92141/101).

Existe algum motivo para usar um `TimeSpan`? Sabe para que ele serve? Nunca use algo que não sabe para que serve e como usá-lo adequadamente. Se quer um horário não deveria usar um `TimeSpan` porque ele é sobre um tempo decorrido e não um horário (um ponto na linha do tempo).

Como não existe um tipo apenas com horário no .NET padrão (alguns usam bibliotecas auxiliares para lidar com isso) você teria que usar um `DateTime`. Mas não pode considerar só horário de qualquer jeito.

Se realmente quer usar um horário precisa da data, seria algo assim:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var horaC1 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
        var horaC2 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0);
        var now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 5, 0, 0);
        if (now >= horaC1 && now <= horaC2 /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3");
        now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0);
        if (now >= horaC1 && now <= horaC2 /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3 ---");
    }
}
```

Comentei a parte que eu não tenho acesso, mudei os dados para serem fixos e mandei imprimir só para facilitar o teste.

Se quiser insistir em usar o intervalo de tempo, pode fazer:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var horaC1 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        var horaC2 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        var now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 5, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        if (now >= horaC1 || now <= horaC2 /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3");
        now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        if (now >= horaC1 || now <= horaC2 /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3 ---");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dc4E4s). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PmXwGT). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/AndOr.cs).

Se fizer isto estará garantindo as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo, dentro da lógica torta que quer usar. Na sua lógica o horário deve ser entre 23 e 6 horas. Então se passar de 23 está dentro do intervalo que deseja, e se ainda não chegou em 6 também está.

Se quiser realmente usar o `&&` você tem que inverter o lógica:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var horaC1 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        var horaC2 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        var now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 5, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        if (!(now < horaC1 && now > horaC2) /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3");
        now = new DateTime(2019, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0).TimeOfDay;
        if (!(now < horaC1 && now > horaC2) /*&& horarioC1Label1.Text != "00:00" && horarioC2Label1.Text != "00:00")*/) WriteLine("Turno 3 ---");
    }
}
```

Muito pior, né?

Note que todos dão o mesmo resultado, o que você deseja.

Answer (score 3):

Tente

```java
if ((hora_now >= var_horaC1) || (hora_now <= var_horaC2)) {}
```

Porque se hora_now for 5 da manhã, será menor que var_horaC2 (6), mas não será maior que var_horaC1 (23).

Comment: eu preciso que satisfaça ao mesmo tempo as condições, o "ou" não funciona neste caso

Comment: considerando que hora_now seja 5 horas da manhã, não há como ele ser ao mesmo tempo maior que 23 horas e menor que 6. 5 < 6 < 23.

Comment: Se fosse 10 horas da manhã ele não seria menor que 6 e nem maior que 23 e o if daria falso e não executaria o código dentro do if

Answer (score -2):

Vou fazer um exemplo em JS prontamente executável para ilustrar que você precisa do || em vez do &&.

```js
document.write("<h1>Com &&, que é o caso original</h1>"); // Equivale a Console.WriteLine();

var i; // Declaração de i
var mensagem = "NTROU no if na hora "; // Declaração e atribuição de mensagem

// Vou passar pelas 24 horas do dia, em passos de uma em uma hora
for (i = 1; i <= 24; ++i)
{
    // AQUI ! if original: se a hora testada for antes que 6 e depois que 23
    if (i <= 6 && /*<<< atenção ao && aqui */ i >= 23)
    {
        // equivale a Console.WriteLine();
        document.write("<p style='color: green;'>E" + mensagem + i + "</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        // Equivale a Console.WriteLine();
        document.write("<p style='color: red;'>NÃO E" + mensagem + i + "</p>");
    }
}

// Equivale a Console.WriteLine("-------------");
document.write("<hr/>");
document.write("<h1>Com ||</h1>"); // Equivale a Console.WriteLine();

// Mesma coisa do for anterior, vou varrer as 24 horas do dia em passos de 1 em 1 hora
for (i = 1; i <= 24; ++i)
{    
    // AQUI! if proposto: se a hora testada for menor que 6 OU maior que 23
    if (i <= 6 || /*<<< atenção ao || aqui */ i >= 23)
    {
        // Equivale a Console.WriteLine();
        document.write("<p style='color: green'>E" + mensagem + i + "</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        // Equivale a Console.WriteLine();
        document.write("<p style='color: red'>NÃO E" + mensagem + i + "</p>");
    }
}
```

Caso você não goste de JS ou tenha tempo de sobra pra copiar e colar e rodar o programa abaixo e queira um exemplo ilustrativo, do tipo ver para crer, de por que o operador deve ser `||`, em C#, segue abaixo (também disponível em https://rextester.com/ECQM6018):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var corPadrao = Console.ForegroundColor;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; 
        Console.WriteLine("Com &&, que é o original");
        Console.ForegroundColor = corPadrao;

        DateTime todayAtMidnight = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime c1 = todayAtMidnight.AddHours(23);
        DateTime c2 = todayAtMidnight.AddHours(6);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 24; ++i)
        {
            DateTime testableTime = todayAtMidnight.AddHours(i);

            if (testableTime >= c1 && testableTime <= c2)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"ENTROU no if na hora {i}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"NÃO ENTROU no if na hora {i}");
            }
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = corPadrao;
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; 
        Console.WriteLine("Com ||");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 24; ++i)
        {
            DateTime testableTime = todayAtMidnight.AddHours(i);

            if (testableTime >= c1 || testableTime <= c2)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine($"ENTROU no if na hora {i}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine($"NÃO ENTROU no if na hora {i}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para transformar a hora que está no `Label` para o tipo `DateTime`, faça o seguinte (este código abaixo é C#/.NET mesmo, antes que reclamem):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var var_horaC1 = now.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(valor_horaC1);
var var_horaC2 = now.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(valor_horaC2);
...
if ((now >= var_horaC1 || now <= var_horaC2) &&
    (var_horaC1 - var_horaC2 != TimeSpan.Zero))
{
    // É o Turno 3.
}
```

Comment: A resposta embora conceitualmente ok, conforme ela mesmo declara que dá um exemplo em JS, não se aplica a pergunta que foi feita especificamente sobre como realizar isso em C#. Nem vou mencionar as diferenças óbvias e os cuidados que é preciso ter entre programar em C# e JS. Acredito que você poderia ter dado uma olhada na sintaxe de C# e usado um [REPL Online](https://repl.it/) pra validar caso acreditasse ser interessante.

Comment: Dei um up no seu comentário!

Comment: Escrevi código C# na minha resposta, não sei se apago ou transformo em JS?

Comment: Acho mais interessante apagar e transformar em C#. Se não quiser perder o que fez em JS, sugiro que faça um Fiddle ou salve o código no GitHub e deixe no formato de um link como uma _referência_. Algo como "Também tenho um exemplo em JS disponível em [link](https://seulink.com) caso deseje".

Comment: Legal, hein? Valeu pelo toque.

Comment: Oi Marcelo, apaguei da resposta coisas que não só mancham a resposta. Sugiro que as respostas sejam só focadas na parte técnica e não em juízo sobre possíveis leitores e a sua vida mais ou menos ocupada.