# Inserir dados do tipo data e moeda de um maskedTextBox no MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, windows, datetime

Ao tentar inserir os dados digitados de um objeto `maskedTextBox`, um do tipo data e outro do tipo moeda, no banco de dados MySQL, onde possuo uma tabela chamada teste, criada conforme comando abaixo:

```
    CREATE TABLE `teste`
(
`tes_id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`tes_data` Date,
`tes_preco` Decimal,
PRIMARY KEY (`tes_id`)
)
```

NO meu formulário, do tipo `WindowsFormApplication`, criado no Visual Studio Community Edition 2015, tenho um botão salvar que tem o código abaixo:

```
 if (incluir)
 {
     string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO teste (tes_data, tes_preco) " + "VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(@TesData,'%d/%m/%Y'), @TesPreco)";
     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conexaoMySQL);
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsert, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesData", txtTes_Data.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesPreco", txtTes_Preco.Text);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     con.Open();
     try
     {
         int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (i > 0) MessageBox.Show("Dado Incluido com Sucesso !!!!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }
 }
 else
 {
     string sqlAlterar = "UPDATE teste SET str_to_date(@TesData,'%d/%m/%Y'), tes_preco=@TesPreco WHERE tes_id=@TesId";
     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conexaoMySQL);
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlAlterar, con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesId", txtTes_Id.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesData", txtTes_Data.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TesPreco", txtTes_Preco.Text);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     con.Open();
     try
     {
         int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (i > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("Dado Atualizado com Sucesso !!!!");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }
 }
 tsbIncluirTes.Enabled = true;
 tsbSalvarTes.Enabled = false;
 tsbCancelarTes.Enabled = false;
 tsbExcluirTes.Enabled = false;
 tstBuscarTesId.Enabled = true;
 tsbBuscarTeste.Enabled = true;
 txtTes_Data.Enabled = false;
 txtTes_Preco.Enabled = false;
 txtTes_Id.Text = "";
 txtTes_Data.Text = "";
 txtTes_Preco.Text = "";
```

Ao clicar no botão salvar, vem a seguinte mensagem de erro do MySQL, conforme abaixo:

> Erro: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have on error in your SQl syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQl server version for the right syntax to use near '('11/03/1965','%d/%m/f%Y'),. tes_preco='l,5'
>   WHERE tes_id= '" at line 1
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>   em MySqI.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(lnt32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(lnt32l statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(lnt32 statementId, Boolean force)
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqICommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqICommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   em Teste_Mascara_Data_Preco.Form1.TsbSalvarTes.Clck(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) na C:\Users\profe\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\Teste_Mascara_Data_Preco\Teste_Mascara_Data_Preco\Form1.cs:linha 76

Não consegui localizar o problema.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não tem muitas informações então não vou dar uma resposta definitiva. O problema é que provavelmente as colunas são do tipo `datetime` e `decimal` (pelo menos deveriam ser algo assim) e está gravando um texto. Então a solução é converter isso para o tipo adequado antes de tentar gravar. Seria algo assim:

```
Convert.ToDatetime(txtTes_Data.Text)
Convert.ToDecimal(txtTes_Preco.Text)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Convert.cs).

Se precisar [pode estabelecer um formato específico para a data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) ou [o valor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_). [Outras soluções são possíveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47673/101). Um simples [`ToString()` pode ser mais adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121440/101).

Mas se houver alguma chance dos [dados serem inválidos para a conversão vai resultar em exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118450/101), o que não é ideal. Aí seria melhor usar um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) na data ou [no valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86684/101).

Tem outros problemas no código (por exemplo uma digitação errada pode quebrar a aplicação), mas não é o foco da pergunta.